# Write condition if string ends with certain string

Tags: perl

I have a string "John says hello". How can I write an `if` condition which would work like this: if the string ends with words "says hello", then ......?

I thought about separating the string with regular expressions first like this:

```
$r =~ /(\w+) (\w+) (.+)/;
my($user,$msg) = ($1,"$2 $3");
if ($msg eq "says hello"){
....
}
```

But, I want to write it without separating it using regex. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to anchor the regex to the end of the string using `$`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $r = 'John says hello';    
if ($r =~ /says hello$/){
    print "found\n"
}
```

You could generalize this by storing your message in a variable:

```
my $r = 'John says hello';
my $msg = 'says hello';
if ($r =~ /$msg$/){
    print "found\n"
}
```

If your message could contain regex metacharacters, you can escape those by placing it between `\Q` and `\E`:

```
if ($r =~ /\Q$msg\E$/){
```

A good resource is [perldoc perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: if ($r =~ /$'says hello'$/) is gonna work too right?

Comment: not yet, i need to connect to vpn and stuff, so it takes time), so I ask theoretically

Comment: and in case of words in the beginning its if ($r =~ /$John/){
    print "found\n"
} ?

Comment: @edzedz: You shouldn't really guess at Perl's syntax when so much good documentation exists for it. If you read the [regex manual page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) you will see that `$` marks the end of the string and `^` marks the beginning of the string.